# unixODBC - easysoft libodbc.a(libodbc.so.1) could not be loaded

Tags: oracle, aix, unixodbc

Running on AIX server.
Unable to get the isql up and running with easy-soft, but we had no issues in getting the query results in sqlplus.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

```
bash-4.3$ isql -v XXXX
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program isql because of the following errors:
        0509-150   Dependent module libodbc.a(libodbc.so.1) could not be loaded.
        0509-022 Cannot load module libodbc.a(libodbc.so.1).
        0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

$ ar -X32_64 -tv libodbc.a
rwxr-xr-x   201/1     698963 Oct 04 11:21 2004 libodbc.so.1
```

Comment: Has it ever worked? Or you installed it recently? Where from did you get it? (My guess: ftp://ftp.unixodbc.org/pub/unixODBC/odbc-aix-5.tar.gz )

Answer (score 0):

You can export `LIBPATH` variable before try to exec the command:

```
export LIBPATH=$LIBPATH:/path/where/is/located/libodbc
isql -v XXXX
```

Comment: Thanks Romeo for your reply. LIBPATH is pointed to easysoft/unixODBC/lib/ , there I could see libodbc file.  after I do cd to that path, i executed : ar -X32_64 -tv libodbc.a
rwxr-xr-x   201/1     698963 Oct 04 11:21 2004 libodbc.so.1

Comment: @Naga, it must be absolute path, not relative

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue resolved.
The problem was wrong oracle client was installed.
Calling application and easysoft was in 32bit, but the oracle client was in 64bit.
Re Installing 32bit oracle client solved our problem.

Regards,
Naga